# no symbol in current context for global variable (or macro)

Tags: debugging, variables, scope, gdb, fortran

I'm new to GDB, and I'm stepping through a function causing me trouble.  I'm trying to print the value of a global variable (which determines control flow) but I'm getting `no symbol in current context`.  I don't know where the symbol is defined, but shouldn't it be present here?

The block I'm looking at:

```
if (present(weights)) then
      numWeights = size(weights,1)
>     if (numWeights == NSPECIES) then
         weightsFull = weights
      else
         weightsFull = weights(1)
      endif
else
      weightsFull = 1.0
endif
```

And I'm trying to get the value of `NSPECIES`

Comment: If that's a macro after all, the behavior could be caused by a [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75631484/gdb-doesnt-support-dwarf-5-macro-sections) in at least gdb 12.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it possible that `NSPECIES` is a macro rather than a variable?  If it is then you will need to compile your program with `-g3` in order to get the macro information included in the binary.

Answer (score 1):

If NSPECIES exists within a namespace, you would need to call

```
(gdb) p '<namespace>::NSPECIES'
```

to view it. You can check by calling

```
(gdb) info variables
```

which lists all the variables defined in the current context. If you want to check the existence of NSPECIES specifically, you can even call

```
(gdb) info variables NSPECIES
```

which will list all defined variables matching that name.

Hope it helps.