# gdb doesn't support DWARF 5 macro sections?

Tags: c, gcc, gdb, dwarf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define A "hello world\n"
void main()
{
    printf(A);
}
```

```
$ gcc -gdwarf-4 -g3 a.c \
&& gdb -ex 'set confirm off' \
       -ex 'break main' \
       -ex 'run' \
       -ex 'p A' \
       -ex q \
       a.out
...
Breakpoint 1, main () at a.c:5
5       printf(A);
$1 = "hello world\n"

$ gcc -gdwarf-5 -g3 a.c \
&& gdb -ex 'set confirm off' \
       -ex 'break main' \
       -ex 'run' \
       -ex 'p A' \
       -ex q \
       a.out
...
Breakpoint 1, main () at a.c:5
5       printf(A);
No symbol "A" in current context.

$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 12.2.1 20230201
...

$ gdb --version
GNU gdb (GDB) 12.1
...
```

Comment: Sounds like [this bug](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=29606), which was already fixed in gdb 13.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As ssbssa [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75631484/gdb-doesnt-support-dwarf-5-macro-sections?noredirect=1#comment133430510_75631484) this looks like a [bug](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=29606) in `gdb-12.1`. The fix is released in `gdb-13.1`

Comment: gdb-13.1 was released [2 weeks ago](https://sourceware.org/gdb/).